# Create a drop down list of pages created using a specific content type

Tags: navigation, nodes

I've created a 'Galleries' page using a field collection so a user can create an infinite number of image links to individual 'Gallery' pages. The individual 'Gallery' pages are created seperately using a different content type.

I need to create a drop down list in the 'Galleries' content type field collection which lists all of the individual 'Gallery' pages which have been created. I've achieved this by adding a Node Reference field into the field collection on the 'Galleries' page which references all of the 'Gallery' content types.

This is as far as I've got, but can't figure out if or how I can use the drop down list values to somehow get the url of the selected pages and output it through the 'Galleries' template page.

Comment: Despite the effort in explaining what the issue is, I'm having trouble understanding what it is that you want to do. Do you have a link or a similar application on the web of what you're after?

Comment: it is a bit confusing - try adding some of the expected user experience to the question - i.e.: the user goes to content type A, clicks on the select list (a node reference to content type B) - when they click on this, i want ??? to happen or be available in ??? area of the page/content/field, etc

Comment: Hi both. I thought it was a tad confusing when I wrote the post. Possibly why I've confused myself as to the best way to achieve this.

Comment: The site I'm creating needs to show the end user an initial page of gallery links containing a thumbnail and title relevant to the gallery type. The admin of the site (not me) needs to be able to add/delete/modify each individual link. Each link will direct users to an work type specific Gallery page (e.g. Kitchens or Bathrooms) containing thumbnails to further Gallery pages which would show individual projects (e.g. Bathroom Project 1/Bathroom Project 2 etc). I'm currently trying the Media Gallery Module, so will let you know how I get on.